# Prompt for file in Microsoft Bot Framework for Skype (node.js)

Tags: node.js, skype, botframework

I'd like to build a Skype bot using Microsoft Bot Framework that can prompt the user to drop a file into the chat and have the bot do stuff with the file, anyone know if this is possible?

[Prompts documentation](http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/dialogs/Prompts/) doesn't mention anything about working with files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while there isn't a Prompt for accepting a file you can use session.send() to tell the user "Send me the file..." and then when they send you the file it should come through as part of the message.  You'd find it through session.message.attachments.

With that said... Adding a Prompt for this isn't a bad idea as it would make it easier to use this as a step in a waterfall.  I filed a enhancement suggestion on our GitHub page.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/74

Comment: Thanks for the response, however it doesn't appear to work. Sending a PDF file session.message.attachments is undefined and inspecting the entire session.message, the only reference to the file is in session.message.text which outputs something like '<files alt="Posted files">\n<file size="25359" index="0" tid="1635679696">File.pdf</file></files>'. Additionally, if sending an image (PNG for example), the bot doesn't receive it at all. Any suggestions?